# HTML wrapper not added to views row

Tags: views, theming, 8, caching, proxies

In drupal8 site, I have views for showing blog content created a twig file  and wrapped with some HTML tag for theming the blog page. Consider I have 10 content on one page. During particular interval for some content/row HTML wrapper in twig is not adding, so the particular content design breaks. I cannot find the reason for this issue. Kindly help to solve.

Note: I have varnish cache enabled.

Actual content.

```
    <div class="blog">
     -- custom tags
       <div class="view-content">    
        {{ content }}
       </div>
    </div>
```

After some time it changes to

```
 <div class="view-content">    
   {{ content }}
 </div>
```

If I clear the cache, it again adds HTML tags to views row.